# Why does doing operations on inequalities preserve the solutions?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

I know that $x>y \implies x \cdot c>y \cdot c, c > 0$ and I can use this rule to solve inequalities.
But why does this operation preserve the solutions for the original inequality?

Example:
If I solve $\frac{1}{2}(x+1) > 4$ I can multiply both sides by $2$ to get $(x+1)>8$
but why do the solutions for $(x+1)>8$ solve $\frac{1}{2}(x+1) > 4$ if the rule is not "if and only if"?

Edit:
I want to understand why some operations that are not "if and only if" preserve the solutions for the original inequality.

$0<x<y \implies x^2<y^2$ but $x^2<y^2$ does not imply $x<y$.

Example #2: $\sqrt{x+2} > 2$ we can use the rule to get $x+2 > 4$ and the solutions for $x+2 > 4$ solve $\sqrt{x+2} > 2$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150058/discussion-on-question-by-mawaior-why-does-doing-operations-on-inequalities-pres); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

$x>y \implies x \cdot c>y \cdot c, c > 0$

Because of:

$x>y \iff x \cdot c>y \cdot c, c > 0$

Comment: What about 0<x<y implies x^2 < y^2? x^2 < y^2 does not imply x < y.

Comment: Some inequalities require us to "square" them.
But here the rule 0<x<y implies x^2 < y^2 is not "if and only if" and we still use it to find the solutions to the original inequality.

Comment: @mawaior: there is a huge difference between multiplying each side with the **same** positive number and squaring both (which means, multiplying with **different** numbers).

Comment: But we still use an "if" type rule to solve an inequality and we get the same solutions.
That's my point, I want to understand why doing some operations that aren't "if and only if" reserve the original solutions.